# Alien Symbiote Computers that eventually have godlike computer-children

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi

I am looking for a book/trilogy that had 21st century earth hit by a wave of alien symbiotes. The symbiotes are seemingly physics/compute constrained and are purely biological, able to manipulate the host's biology. People adapted to having them and at some point the protagonist starts to "jailbreak" his symbiote. This is done in concert with increasing the % of the protag's bones that the symbiote has replaced. The protag is joined by a female love interest, who also jailbreaks her symbiote.

Later in the story, I believe they get abducted by the alien race that created the symbiotes on the basis of them being good candidates/special. They disagree with this and eventually return to Earth. Their symbiotes bud off Godlike versions of themselves into a kind of bio-house and leave the original symbiote-human pair unascended, solving the main crisis.

I have eliminated:

- The 5th Wave by Rick Yancey
- Parasite Eve by Hideaki Sena
- The Bobiverse series by Dennis E. Taylor

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: ltmauve got it! I think I read this around 2015-2016

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like a webnovel simply called *Symbiote*, written and published by someone with the screen name of "Farmerbob1" on their WordPress site.

[Here's a link to the first chapter.](https://farmerbob1.wordpress.com/2013/11/13/chapter-1-a-meeting-of-the-minds/) This what you were looking for?